# npm process won't exit after closing Windows Terminal

Tags: node.js, windows-terminal, npm

This seems to be a bug in either npm or the Windows Terminal, or perhaps there's a setting I'm not aware of. I have a simple node app where I've installed express, and has a single *index.js* file with this code:

```
import express from 'express';

const port = process.argv[2]
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`Hello from port ${port}`))
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is running at http://localhost:' + port));
```

I also have this in my *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Then I open Windows Terminal on my project's directory and do `npm start 3000`, then visit http://localhost:3000 and then close the terminal. When I refresh the page, I can see that the server is still running, and there's no way to stop it other than by relogging the user.

The problem is solved either by running the command on Power Shell or CMD, or by directly running `node index.js` on Windows Terminal. So somehow the combination of both Windows Terminal and npm seems to be causing the problem.

Does anyone know a way to avoid this and make sure the process stops when I close Windows Terminal?

Comment: Windows Terminal is extremely buggy, wouldn't recommend using it personally. Could be related https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15373

Comment: @Destroy666 Yeah that's a shame since it seemed pretty cool, now I'm back on PS. Perhaps you know any alternative? I just need tabs and being able to launch the tabs from the command line (something like `wt` on Terminal).

Comment: There are bunch of alternatives. But this question belongs more on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered